# javascript project. nested table loop

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

I need to create an html table with data from this [spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuVN0.png)

using a nested javascript loop. It puzzles me because when I think of what a loop does creating a table seems weird.

I really have no idea how to start this. I also need to detect clicking on total loan costs as well as create an event-initiated function that shows the interest charged on the loan. Thank You in advance!

```
  for (var i=0;i<1;i++)
{document.writeln("<table></table>");

    {break;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<6;i++)
    { 
        table.writeln("<tr>");
        {for (var i=0,i<21,i++)
            table.writeln("<td>");
        }
    }

}

    var prin=10000;
   //var months=(6,12,18,24);
  //period in years 
 var period=(.5,1,1.5,2);
 var percent=(4,5,6);
 //rate in percent
 var rate=(.04,.05,.06);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is not valid! Try hitting "F12" in your browser window to open developer tools. If you can find the javascript console, it'll display your javascript errors with the offending line numbers (if you can't find the console, google for "javascript console firefox" substituting "firefox" for your browser's name).

Why do you have the opening "{" in front of the "break" statement? Also, the "}" after the break statement closes your loop, and the "break" statement breaks out of the loop on the first iteration.

Your third loop is incorrect, the "{" should be after the "for (...)"... and lastly you cannot use "i" as the variable for all the loops like that, because the interior loops are constantly resetting the "i" variable that the outer loops still are using.

You must use unique counters, like i, j, k, for each loop that is nested.

This is a nested loop with 3 levels of nesting (although you don't need 3 loops):

```
for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j<6; j++) {
     table.writeln("<tr>");

     for (var k=0; k<21; k++) {
        table.writeln("<td>"); // open cell tag
        // put stuff inside of cell?
        table.writeln("</td>"); // close cell tag
     }

     // You should CLOSE your table tag here (although you don't have to since modern browsers will interpret the next opening "tr" tag as the end of the old "tr" tag.
     table.writeln("</tr>");

   }
}

var period=(.5,1,1.5,2); // this code does absolutely nothing.
```

Also, you aren't dealing with the table tags correctly -- you write an empty table with this line: `document.writeln("<table></table>");`

What you should do is:

```
document.writeln("<table>");

for( ... {
  //all your for loop to create rows/cells
}

document.writeln("</table>"); // close the table tag
```

I recommend you head to w3c schools and do some HTML and Javascript tutorials.

HTML Basics
http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Javascript tutorials
http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Javascript loops
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp